# T-SQL Using a column value to get the corresponding attribute in an xml column

Tags: t-sql, xml-parsing

I have the following setup...

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
Id int Identity(1,1),
Choices xml,
Selection int
)
```

```
INSERT INTO #Test (Choices, Selection) VALUES  
('<ChoiceInfo>
  <Choice Choice="T1" Score="1"/>
  <Choice Choice="T3" Score="2"/>
  <Choice Choice="T9" Score="5"/>
  <Choice Choice="T6" Score="7"/>
</ChoiceInfo>', 5)

INSERT INTO #Test (Choices, Selection) VALUES  
('<ChoiceInfo>
  <Choice Choice="T2" Score="3"/>
  <Choice Choice="T4" Score="1"/>
  <Choice Choice="T8" Score="6"/>
  <Choice Choice="T7" Score="8"/>
</ChoiceInfo>', 6)
```

```
SELECT * FROM #Test
```

```
SELECT Id,
Choices.value('(/ChoiceInfo/Choice/@Choice)[3]', 'nvarchar(64)') AS Choice,
Choices.value('(/ChoiceInfo/Choice/@Score)[3]', 'nvarchar(64)') AS Score
FROM #Test
WHERE Id = 1
```

```
DROP TABLES #Test
```

What i would like to do is instead of using a hard coded value - i would like to use the value of the column "Selection" to pull out the correct "Choice"
So in the case of the first row, i would get the value "T9" and for the second row, i would get the value "T8"

I have tried replacing the literal with sql:column but this gives me an error - requires a singleton - not sure if i am going down the right road.

Thanks